# Divide md5 function with colon (:)

Tags: php, hash, md5

How can I divide a md5 function with a colon?

Currently I have this:

```
$ms = md5($transactionid:$secretkey);
```

But that code is invalid.

I can divide it with a "." but not a ":"?

Comment: As a sidenote, are you really sure using `md5` is the way to go in your case? If this data will ever be exposed, it won't be such a problem to extract both `transactionId` and `secretKey`, as you explicitly separated them.

Comment: What do you mean by "devide a function"?

Comment: @raina77ow I am trying to use matomy.com and in their guide, they say to use md5.

Comment: This is basic PHP syntax, how to concatenate strings. It has nothing to do specifically with MD5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ms = md5($transactionid.':'.$secretkey);
```

You need to concatenate with `.`